# aaSorting in datatables not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatable, datatables

I have the following html in my first column. It shows a icon and an anchor tag.

```
     <tr class="even">
        <td class=" sorting_1">
            <span data-sortvalue="0">
               <img title="icon" src="icon.png">
               <a href="path to page" title="0">0</a>
            </span>
       </td>
     </tr>

     <tr class="odd">
        <td class=" sorting_1">
             <span data-sortvalue="1">
               <img title="icon" src="icon.png">
               <a href="path to page" title="1">1</a>
             </span>
        </td>
     </tr>

     <tr class="even">
         <td class=" sorting_1">
             <span data-sortvalue="2">
               <img title="icon" src="icon.png">
               <a href="path to page" title="2">2</a>
             </span>
         </td>
     </tr>
....................
...................
...................
```

I am using `aaSorting[0, 'asc']`

In chrome, the `0` value is always staying at the top if the column is sorted either ascending or descending. All the remaining values are getting sorted accordingly.

In firefox, the sorting is completely broken.

Answer (score 1):

The data attributes for sorting on your span tags need to be on the td tag. They should also be changed to just 'data-sort' or 'data-order'.

Check out [DataTables data-attributes docs here](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html)

```
 <tr class="even">
    <td class=" sorting_1" data-sort="0">
        <span>
           <img title="icon" src="icon.png">
           <a href="path to page" title="0">0</a>
        </span>
   </td>
 </tr>
 ...
 ...
```